# Target release_unpack_ios failed: Failes to strip bitcode error Xcode 15

Tags: flutter, xcode, build, bitcode

I'm having this problem when trying to build my flutter project to my phone through xcode. I has the project working fine in another mac but now that i switched to this one (using Sonoma) I got this error that I'm not able to solve. I couldn't find any solution or an already created topic about it.

[image: Screenshot of xcode errors]

I tried to change the bitcode settings in Xcode but nothing changes, as well as modifying my podfile.